# How can I allow input of multiple lines of text?

Tags: html

I am looking for a way in which I can create an input, in which you can enter multiple lines of code. The standard `input="text"` doesn't work since it is a single line.

Comment: Did you actually first try google? You need a `textarea` for this.

Comment: Actually I did, when I intered "input paragraphs of text" I got results for people trying to show something which has already been set by the user (for example set the inner HTML of a div)

Comment: Yup, use a `textarea` element -- BTW this question has nothing to do with either html5 or css3 specifically.

Comment: You are probably right. I edited the tag to just "Html"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element.

```
<textarea name="yourInputName" rows="4"></textarea>
```

*To set a more exact width and height of your textarea you can use CSS and set the `height` and `width` properties, instead of using the `rows` and `cols` attributes on the element.*

Comment: then Accept it and close que. mate

Answer (score 1):

For multiple line input you can use 
`<textarea name="field_name"></textarea>`
instead of `<input type="text">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
Enter text here...</textarea>
```

and refer http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_form